# Change max batch size in MongoDB Java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I came across the Javadoc of DBCursor in the MongoDB Java driver ([http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#batchSize(int)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#batchSize%28int%29)). There it is mention that the maximum batch size overall is 4mb.

Is this related to MongoDB or can this be configured somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, the maximum batch size is related to the maximum document size in MongoDB which is between 4MB and 16MB, depending on the version you're using.

However, this shouldn't really matter unless you're trying to squeeze the last bit of performance or you have a very laggy database connection. What are you up to?

Comment: Thought this as well. I have large data sets that need to be delivered to a client. The client itself calls a servlet where I stream the data from the DBCursor directly to the stream. And when downloading, one can see a short break around every 4mb.

The overall target is that I would like to stream directly from the DBCursor to a output stream of a servlet (loading everything into memory is not a good approach as the response could get up to 500mb) .

Comment: To mitigate the breaks, I guess one would have to teach the driver some configurable prefetch before it reaches the end of the current batch on the client. I guess you should raise this on the newsgroup, but the requirement sounds a bit exotic to me. Responses of 500MB are huge; I guess the user won't page through all this? Maybe you can streamline your result sets?

Comment: Well the result is not for a web client or better say for an online client. It is part of a sync algorithm and therefor we need to transmit that amount of data to the client. 500 mb is a huge amount of data and also represents a worst case (luckliy :)). Of course those minimal delays between the refetch are minimal and this shouldn't really affect the overall performance. I just wondered if that is possible.